# How to show limit posts per page

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Can I show 5 posts on the first page and 8 posts on the second and following pages?

```
$pagenum = $paged;
if ($pagenum=='') { $pagenum =1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&paged='.$pagenum);
} else query_posts('posts_per_page=8&paged='.$pagenum);
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts( ) ) : the_post();
```

its work, but weird on page 2 the post start from eighth
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the fly I would say you have to use the [`offset`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)-parameter on the post query for right pagination.

**Pseudo Code**

```
$pagenum = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
if ($pagenum == 1 ) :
    query_posts('posts_per_page=5&paged='.$pagenum);
else :
    query_posts('posts_per_page=8&paged='.$pagenum.'&offset=5'); //set the offset
endif;
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts( ) ) : the_post();
```

**Edit:** Just saw in the documentation that the `offset`-paramater ignores/overrides the `paged`-parameter. If you get into troubles have a look at the provided [workaround](http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination).

Comment: I set the offset to 
$offsetvalue = 5 + 8*($pagenum-2);

Thanks @pbaldauf :)